# How to retrieve output param from Stored Procedure with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures, hibernate-4.x

I am trying to execute a Stored Procedure which updates a column and retrieves the filename from the same table after updating

StoredProcedure:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE `update_count`(
    IN in_testID                VARCHAR(64),
    OUT out_FileName        VARCHAR(100),
    OUT out_Message         VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    UPDATE files SET count=count+1 WHERE testID=in_testID;    
    SELECT FileName INTO out_FileName FROM files WHERE testID = in_testID;    
    SET out_Message = 'File updated uccessfully';
END
```

JavaCode to execute this StoredProcedure:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL update_count(:in_testID, @out_FileName, @out_Message)").addEntity(FilesBean.class)
.setParameter("in_testID",body.getTestId());
query.executeUpdate();
```

Updated the `query.executeUpdate()` with `query.list()`. But the line returning a error `ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data`

I need to fix this with using the createSQLQuery

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is return the out parameter as part of the returning parameters (relevant only if you have access to the store procedures).
just add a store procedure like the following one

```
create procedure myProcedure_only_in_prams (
   in in_Id int)
begin
call myProcedure(in_id,@out_Id) ;
select @out_id
END;
```

after done that it quite simple to use it with Hibernate in the following way

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"CALL myProcedure_only_in_parms (:in_Id)")
.setParameter("in_id", 123);
List result = query.list();
```

The result contains the out parameter, if you want return multiply parameters you can add it by doing **select @parm1,@parm2,... ,@parmn**

Hope it helped